Embedding SMuFL in TEI documents
I have a general question regarding embedding SMuFL in TEI files. I have tried various cases, but it seems not to be working for me. Here is a very simple example:
xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <text>
    <body>
      <p> This is a test:
        <g ref="https://smufl-browser.edirom.de/luteGermanAUpper.xml"/>
      </p>
    </body>
  </text>
</TEI>

xsl:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>SMuFL test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

In the resulted html I don't see the visual representation of <g> . What am I doing wrong?
